# PowerShell - CSV with rows constantly being added, how to import only new rows?

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

In a Powershell script currently using Import-CSV and a ForEach-Object loop, how do I have the script remember the last record that it did an action on and resume with the next record?

Imagine the CSV has 1000 rows and the script runs successfully. Then 500 rows are added to the CSV by an external process. How do I run only on the 500 added rows?

Comment: I would assume the _external process_ is leaving some reference of how many rows were added right? I don't see how this would be possible without that.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It is not currently, but it could theoretically be changed

Comment: Then the answer provided by mklement0 should work, `$lastLineImported` should be updated based on that value that the external process is leaving as reference.

Answer (score 1):

The following is conceptually simple, but won't perform well:

```sh
$lastLineImported = 1000

$fromCsv = Get-Content file.csv |
             Select-Object -Skip $lastLineImported | 
               ConvertFrom-Csv -Header (
                 (Get-Content -TotalCount 1 file.csv) -split ',' -replace '"'
               )
```